# Magento 2 require is not defined

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

After installing magento 2 CE, I had

`ReferenceError: require is not defined` in console. I found this solution

`c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f d:\projects\localsites\magento2.local\magento\bin\magento -- setup:static-content:deploy`
And that helps me, but every time when I flush my static cache, this problem  happens again. How I can solve this problem "forever".

Comment: at what part of your module, you're having this error?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the developer mode, and the static content will be deployed automatically (no need for `setup:static-content:deploy`).

Comment: After flush static cache, any files are not build in this folder (pub/static) it is normal?